# Show only specific month dates hide prev/next dates in antd calendar when selecting month from dropdown

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need only to show specific/current month dates in antd calendar. no need to show next month dates in calendar e.g sep -> only show sep dates and remove oct dates from end in antd.
this code not working

```
 const dateCellRender = (date, calendarDates, isFeed, timeZone) => {
  const color = getCalendarDatesColor(date, calendarDates, isFeed, timeZone);
  const isCurrentMonth = date.month() === new Date().getMonth();

  return (
      <>
        { isCurrentMonth ? 
        <div className={"date-cell " + color}>
       {/* <Badge status={date?.()} /> */}
       <span>{date?.date()}</span>
       </div> : null
      }
   </>
  );
 };
```